# Realm, copyFromRealm, exclude relation from result

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to exclude some relationship(s) from result of copyFromRealm?

For example I have a class

```
open class City : RealmObject() {
    var id : String? = null
    var name : String? = null
    var streets : RealmList<Street>? = null
}
```

I want to get a list of unmanaged objects - but I don't want streets to be included in that result.

Comment: Sorry but why you don't want to receive streetlist? Just do not handle it.

Comment: It takes time to make detached copy of all Street objects + memory

Comment: And... let's see a case when every Street also has a list of some objects, Houses for example. In this case the resulting list can be really big

Comment: well i don't think storing big datasets locally on the phone is a good idea anyway. and realm is really fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Realm.copyFromRealm(Iterable<E> realmObjects, int maxDepth)` and use `0` for the `maxDepth`. See doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.2.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-java.lang.Iterable-int-).

```
City unmanagedCity = realm.copyFromRealm(managedCity, 0);
```